# Is there a standard for this file format?

Tags: file-format, json, yaml

I run an Ubiquity Edge router which itself is based upon [Vyatta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyatta) (it does not matter, it is just in case someone knew the product).

The configuration file looks like that

```
(...)
service {
    dhcp-server {
        disabled false
        global-parameters "option rfc3118-auth code 90 = string;"
        global-parameters "option SIP code 120 = string;"
        global-parameters "option Vendor-specific code 125 = string;"
        hostfile-update disable
        shared-network-name LAN {
            authoritative disable
            subnet 192.168.10.0/24 {
                default-router 192.168.10.1
                dns-server 192.168.10.1
                domain-name example.com
                lease 86400
                ntp-server 192.168.10.1
                start 192.168.10.50 {
                    stop 192.168.10.254
                }
                static-mapping domotique {
                    ip-address 192.168.10.5
                    mac-address 26:e9:0c:53:40:41
                }
(...)
```

**Would anyone know whether this is a well-known file/content formatting standard?**

It remotely looks like a junction between JSON and YAML and I am pretty sure I have seen it already somewhere else.

Comment: Looks kinda similar to nginx config. I don't think it's something standard, though.

Comment: It's really similar to JunOS (Juniper) configuration. I don't think it's a standard format, but any tooling for JunOS would work reasonably well on Vyatta/EdgeOS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [here](https://blog.vyos.io/writing-migration-scripts-and-manipulating-vyos-config-files-outside-vyos-just-got-easier) that vyatta used [XORP](http://www.xorp.org/) routing protocol in the past (at least in the past…) and so that's probably the origin of this config configuration file. It uses [XorpConfigParser](https://github.com/vyos/vyatta-config-migrate/blob/current/scripts/XorpConfigParser.pm) perl module. But I didn't have any luck finding a name for this format.

Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XORP#User_interface) about XORP config format

Juniper used very similar configuration format in JUNOS, they just referred to it as cli configuration format. These days they support JSON as well.